# Django - detect mobile device in views

Tags: django

I am already using a device detection (http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2228/) in my templates and trying to also make it work in views, so i can redirect to the app store if a user comes from an iPhone.

So I already had:

```
import re

def mobile(request):

    device = {}

    ua = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '').lower()

    if ua.find("iphone") > 0:
        device['iphone'] = "iphone" + re.search("iphone os (\d)", ua).groups(0)[0]

    if ua.find("ipad") > 0:
        device['ipad'] = "ipad"

    if ua.find("android") > 0:
        device['android'] = "android" + re.search("android (\d\.\d)", ua).groups(0)[0].translate(None, '.')

    # spits out device names for CSS targeting, to be applied to <html> or <body>.
    device['classes'] = " ".join(v for (k,v) in device.items())

    return {'device': device }
```

And then created a class in tools/middleware.py:

```
from tools.context_processor import mobile

class detect_device(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        device = mobile(request)

        request.device = device
```

Added the following to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in the settings.py:

```
'tools.middleware.detect_device'
```

And in views.py I created:

```
def get_link(request):
    if request.device.iphone:
        app_store_link = settings.APP_STORE_LINK
        return HttpResponseRedirect(app_store_link)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

But I am getting the error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'iphone'

Comment: FYI, `find` returns an index of the first match so it could theoretically return 0. Your checks should look like this `if ua.find("iphone") > -1` instead, as it returns -1 for no match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IT's a dictionary, not a class.

Complete view:

```
def get_link(request):
    if 'iphone' in request.device['device']:
        app_store_link = settings.APP_STORE_LINK
        return HttpResponseRedirect(app_store_link)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Thanks, almost correct, but if you will change to - if 'iphone' in request.device['device'] - then I will vote you up :)